# How do I find the row and column that has the highest value?

Tags: c#

How do I find the row and column that has the highest value with a C# program? The program asks the user to input how many rows and columns are in the program then asks for the numbers. Say I put in 4 columns and 3 rows for the matrix and then put in these numbers:

```
89 11 22 44
29 51 80 20
33 10 45 10
```

the output that I need in this case would be, "First largest value is located at row 1 and column 1". How do I get the program to find where the highest value is located as far as the program printing which row and column the highest value is in. When I try to call the method to get the return value, it won't print it. Here is my attempted code:

```cs
using System;

namespace locateLargest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] arrayPart1 = new int[3, 4];

            for (int row = 0; row < arrayPart1.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < arrayPart1.GetLength(1); column++)
                {
                    arrayPart1[row, column] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }

            }





            for (int row = 0; row < arrayPart1.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < arrayPart1.GetLength(1); column++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Value at [" + row + ", " + column + "]: " + arrayPart1[row, column] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("The highest value in the array is at "+largest) 
            }

        }


            public static int[] LocateLargest(int[,] someArray)
                {

        {
            int largest = someArray[0, 0];
            int row, column;
            int maxRow = 0;
            int maxCol = 0;
            for (row = 0; row < someArray.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (column = 0; column < someArray.GetLength(1); column++)
                {
                    if (someArray[row, column] > largest)
                    {
                        maxRow = row;
                        maxCol = column;
                        largest = someArray[row, column];
                    }
                }

            }
            return largest;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, this is a homework question. Sorry for not stating that earlier, I've been trying to figure out this program for hours and am tired.

Comment: So what are you having problems with? The only problem I see is that you did not *try* (or post that try). Do you get errors? Compile time or runtime? What happens when you actually write code to do what is asked?

Comment: Assume that the first entry (0, 0) is the highest number and compare every other entry with that number. If any number is bigger, set it to your temporary variable. That's the easiest way.

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know what to put, I am completely new to programming

Comment: Then please get a good book or tutorial. Despite what SE makes you want to think this is not a site for *learning*, it lacks structure and feedback required. We help with *specific* problems, not with those broad, generic "I don't know how" questions that students have. Look at your textbook or the task your teacher gave you, I'm sure they had a plan for you on how to solve this. That is the resource you should go to for unspecific help. The other option would be to *try* and then when you have a *specific* problem (for example a wrong result or compile error), post it here.

Comment: @Techgeelgal19: and that won't change if you don't really try to think about finding a solution for yourself. When you try and fail, we can help explain where you are going wrong...

Comment: There is a Max-Function in Linq what is excaly doing what you need, but it is not working with 2d arrays. If you have an Enumerable you could use `list.SelectMany(x => x).Max()`

Comment: @nvoigt  I have edited but my return statement from the method won't print

Comment: @Johan Donne I have edited but my return statement from the method won't print

Comment: @Techgeekgal19: almost there: the return type for your 'LocateLargest' is wrong: you declare an int-array (int[])  but return an int ('largest').

Comment: @JohanDonne am I supposed to both declare and return an int or both declare and return an int-array? this is confusing

Comment: @JohanDonne because the int array is not embedded. The Program reads the array from the user input

Comment: @JohanDonne changing the return type messes up the whole program

Comment: You pass an int[] (the userinput) as parameter and return an int (the largest value) as return type :  int LocateLargest(int[,] someArray)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way for a beginner to go about this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] arrayPart1 = new int[3, 4];
    for (int row = 0; row < arrayPart1.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < arrayPart1.GetLength(1); column++)
        {
            arrayPart1[row, column] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < arrayPart1.GetLength(0); row++)
     {
          for (int column = 0; column < arrayPart1.GetLength(1); column++)
          {
                Console.Write("Value at [" + row + ", " + column + "]: " + arrayPart1[row, column] + "\t");
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
          Console.WriteLine("The highest value in the array is at "+ LocateLargest (arrayPart1)).ToString ()) 
     }
}

int LocateLargest(int[,] someArray)
{
    int largest = someArray[0, 0];
    int row, column;
    int maxRow = 0;
    int maxCol = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < someArray.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < someArray.GetLength(1); column++)
         {
            if (someArray[row, column] > largest)
            {
                maxRow = row;
                maxCol = column;
                largest = someArray[row, column];
         }
     }
     Console.WriteLine("The largest value is at row " + maxRow.ToString() +  "and column " + maxCol.ToString());
    return largest; 
}
```

Comment: I would need to return largest to the main so it can be printed from the main cause I get an error saying I need to return something, which is what I need to do, but I'm having trouble trying to write the return statement and then print it from the main

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var input = new []
{
    "89 11 22 44",
    "29 51 80 20",
    "33 10 45 10",
};

var result =
    input
        .Select((line, row) => new
        {
            row,
            columns =
                line
                    .Split(' ')
                    .Select((number, column) => new
                    {
                        column,
                        value = int.Parse(number)
                    }) 
        })
        .SelectMany(x => x.columns, (x, y) => new { x.row, y.column, y. value })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.value)
        .First();

Console.WriteLine($"The largest value is {result.value} at row {result.row + 1} and column {result.column + 1}");
```

It gives:

> The largest value is 89 at row 1 and column 1